# Embed native sql inside cognos frameowrk manager that accepts a parameter

Tags: cognos

I need to embed a native oracle sql statement inside COGNOS framework manager. This link describes how to do it.
e.g:

```
select cust_name from cust where cust_id = '111'
```

http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/cognos8-l/native-query-in-framework-manager-query-subject-2374263

Now is there a way to embed an SQL inside COGNOS FM that also accepts a parameter.
e/g:

```
select cust_name from cust where cust_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the prompt macro as described here: 
[Creating prompts with query macros](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m1/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.10.1.1.doc/c_using_macro.html#using_macro) 
Your expression should look something like this:

```
select cust_name from cust where cust_id = #prompt('prmCutsId','integer')#
```

Ofcourse you can expand it by providing default value, or use the promptmany macro so supply list of values (and not just one value). 
You can really do nice things with macros in Cognos, but you have to know exactly what you are doing.